# Regex Ask to match one part of a string, capture another part of the string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am using python re to grab the end of the string. The example is simplified to make it easier but this will have to be done in regex.

The example goes as follows

the string will always start with "abc" and have content I need to grab after

"abc123" should match with 123

"abc456" should match with 456

"123" should have no matches, it doesn't have abc at the front

I cannot figure out the pattern to use to get the results. What pattern should I use? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookbehind like this: `(?<=abc)\d+` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-23), or you could use an expression like `abc(\d+)` and look at capture group 1 (e.g. `re.match(r"abc(\d+)", "abc").group(1)`).

Comment: This is a perfect response to a basic question. Appreciate it!